# React native agora detect all the users that is currently in the voice call

Tags: react-native, agora.io

I am currently using react native agora to create a clubhouse like app and I was wondering is it possible to detect all the users that is currently in the voice call? I'm using the Live broadcasting type for my call.

```
engine.joinChannel(token,"room_name", null, user)

engine.setChannelProfile(ChannelProfile.LiveBroadcasting);
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by the following lines of code

```js
 engine.enableAudioVolumeIndication(200, 3, true)
 // res is an array with all users speaker volume
 engine.addListener("AudioVolumeIndication", (res) => {
      console.log('audio volume indication', res);
    });
// return the speaker with highest volume for a given period of time
 engine.addListener("ActiveSpeaker", (res) => {
      console.log('active speaker', res);
    });
```